# Адаптивный дизайн  - колонки

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая проблема: на сайте есть две колонки. Одна - sitebar - фикс. размер (254px), а вторая - динамический размер (max-width: 1100px min-width: 668px). Помогите реализовать  (в общем виде).

Что я сделал сам:

```
#sitebar {
position: relative;
width: 254px;
float: left;
}

#content-right-part {
float: right;
max-width: 1100px;
width: 100%;
min-width: 668px;
}
```

При таком раскладе правая колонка чуть-чуть уменьшается, а потом перескакивает на следующую строку. Попытавшись решить эту проблему, сделал так:

```
content {
    display: block;
    width: 1400px; /*max size*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
content section {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Однако проблема в том, что "пропала" адаптивность. То есть просто появляется скролл.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: width: 1400px - ? А как здесь будет адаптивность?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Как я написал выше: так я сделал для того, чтобы блоки не переносились. + width: 1400px - для родителя. А дочерние элементы могут быть адаптивными (или я ошибаюсь?..)

Comment: Хорошо, возможно, Вы правы. Но как тогда запретить блокам (<section>) переходить на следующую строку?

Чуть подробней о проблеме: при динамическом размере правого блока, он (контент) недостаточно быстро уменьшается. То есть первые "два" px нормально, а потом ему места не хватает, и он перескакивает на следующую строку...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно задавать ширину основному контенту. Минимальную ширину можно задать врапперу на малых разрешениях. Лучше использовать class, а не id там, где это возможно.

```
<main>
    <h1>Responsive columns</h1>
    <section class="main_sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </section>
    <section class="main_content">
        Main content
    </section>
</main>

h1 {
    font-family:Arial, san-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    text-align:center;
}

main, .main_content, .main_sidebar   {
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}

main {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1024px;
    margin-top:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.main_sidebar {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height:auto;
    background:red;

}

.main_content {
background:green;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqjm49qd/4/)

Comment: Благодарю. Помогли :)